# FlatMapCompletable doesn't continue Rx chain but flatmap with a completable with "andThen(Observable.just(true)" does work?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm trying to chain a completable into my Rx chain and when I do so the chain never finishes in the onError or onComplete.

When I step through the code, my completables code is executed.  I can even add logging and see it log in it's own doOnComplete()

The below will log "I Completed" but will not go into the the error or complete callback.

```
 profileRepo.getLocalProfileIfAvailableElseRemote()
                .flatMapCompletable { profile ->
                    userRoutingRepo.disableRule(profile.account_uid, userRoutingRule.id)
                            .doOnComplete {
                                Log.i("I COMPLETED", "I COMPLETED")
                            }
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeBy(
                        onError = { error ->
                            //do error
                        },
                        onComplete = {
                           //do success
                        }
                ).addTo(disposable)
```

if I instead use flatMap and use the andThen to return a boolean observable, it will work

```
 profileRepo.getLocalProfileIfAvailableElseRemote()
                .flatMap { profile ->
                    userRoutingRepo.disableRule(profile.account_uid, userRoutingRule.id)
                            .doOnComplete {
                                Log.i("I COMPLETED", "I COMPLETED")
                            }.andThen(Observable.just(true))
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeBy(
                        onError = { error ->
                         //do error
                        },
                        onNext = {
                           //do next
                        }
                ).addTo(disposable)
```

I've tried adding a "andThen" to the flatMapCompletable version and calling Completable.complete() but that doesn't work either?

I can't figure out why my completable is completing, but refuses to work with flatMapCompletable?

EDIT: This is an update of my complete attempt that does not work

Note `userRoutingService.disableRule(accountUid, ruleId)` is the retrofit interface

```
 profileRepo.getLocalProfileIfAvailableElseRemote()
                .flatMapCompletable { profile ->
                    userRoutingRepo.disableRule(profile.account_uid, userRoutingRule.id)
                            .andThen(Completable.complete())
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeBy(
                        onError = { error ->
                          Log.i("TAG", "ERROR")
                        },
                        onComplete = {
                            Log.i("TAG", "COMPLETE")
                        }
                ).addTo(disposable)

 override fun disableRule(accountUid: String, ruleId: String): Completable {
        return activeStateToggler(userRoutingSourceApi.disableRule(accountUid, ruleId),
                ruleId,
                false)
    }



override fun disableRule(accountUid: String, ruleId: String): Completable {
        return userRoutingService.disableRule(accountUid, ruleId)
                .doOnError { error ->
                    authenticationValidator.handleAuthenticationExceptions(error)
                }
    }

    private fun activeStateToggler(completable: Completable,
                                   ruleId: String,
                                   stateOnSuccess: Boolean
    ): Completable {
        return completable
                .doOnSubscribe {
                    stateTogglingInProgress.add(ruleId)
                }
                .doOnComplete {
                    stateTogglingInProgress.remove(ruleId)
                    getLocalUserRule(ruleId)?.active = stateOnSuccess
                    stateTogglingInProgressPublishSubject.onNext(UserRoutingStateToggleSubjectType.Success)
                }
                .doOnError {
                    stateTogglingInProgress.remove(ruleId)
                    stateTogglingInProgressPublishSubject.onNext(UserRoutingStateToggleSubjectType.Error(
                            it))
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what flatMapCompletable does:

> Maps each element of the upstream Observable into CompletableSources,
> subscribes to them and waits until the upstream and all
> CompletableSources complete.

When using flatMapCompletable, the Completable that you return will wait for the upstream's Observable terminal event (onComplete).

When using flatMapCompletable, use it only if you are sure that everything up in the chain completes.

In your case it doesn't work because your source Observable is hot and never completes.

Answer (score 0):

When using `flatMapCompletable`, you need to return `Completable.complete()` yourself.

edit:

```
 profileRepo.getLocalProfileIfAvailableElseRemote()
     .flatMap { profile ->
         userRoutingRepo.disableRule(profile.account_uid, userRoutingRule.id)
             .doOnComplete { Log.i("I COMPLETED", "I COMPLETED") } }
     .flatMapCompletable { () -> { Completable.complete() } }
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribeBy(
         onError = { error ->
             //do error
         },
         onNext = {
             //do next
         }
    ).addTo(disposable)
```

edit 2: since `disposableRule` is a `Completable`

```
 profileRepo.getLocalProfileIfAvailableElseRemote()
     .flatMapCompletable { profile ->
         userRoutingRepo.disableRule(profile.account_uid, userRoutingRule.id)
             .doOnComplete { Log.i("I COMPLETED", "I COMPLETED") }
             .andThen(Completable.complete().doOnCompleted { Log.i("comp2", "comp2")) }
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribeBy(
         onError = { error ->
             //do error
         },
         onNext = {
             //do next
         }
    ).addTo(disposable)
```

edit 3: working sample

```
Observable.just(1)
    .flatMapCompletable { profile ->
        Completable.complete()
            .doOnComplete { Log.i("I COMPLETED", "I COMPLETED") }
            .andThen(Completable.complete().doOnComplete { Log.i("I COMPLETED", "I COMPLETED 2") })}
    .subscribeBy(
        onError = { error ->
        },
        onComplete = {
            Log.d("I COMPLETED", "I COMPLETED 3")
        })
```

Comment: That didn't work though? This does not complete.      .flatMapCompletable { profile ->
                    userRoutingRepo.disableRule(profile.account_uid, userRoutingRule.id).andThen(Completable.complete())
                }

Comment: The edit doesn't compile.  It gives an error because disable rule is a completable but it's expecting an observable.

Comment: Edit2 is just back to the same problem I originally had.  Anything after the disableRule call and it's .doOnComplete do not execute, including the andThen.  The subscribe by onError or onComplete is never reached =(

Comment: post your entire code. That's working for me. Make sure you use `.andThen()` and not `.andThen { }`

Comment: What you posted without using a "real" completable works, but it does not work when the returned result of disable rule is a completable.  I don't actually want any extra logic in the andThen I'm just trying to figure out how to make it read it as complete.  I updated my question with the full disable rule logic, which all gets executed properly.